# Using scala.tools.nsc.interpreter for intelligent Autocompletion

Tags: scala, autocomplete, intellisense, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I'm looking forward to make my own IDE for Scala. It's supposed to be something easy, not a full fledged one. Nontheless one of the basic features it should have it's intelligent autocomplete (Aka intellisense). Due to the lack of documentation I'm asking this community for help. I'm looking forward to make a basic snippet in order to add it to my current code. This is what i have so far:

```
val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
val settings = engine.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
// MyScalaClass is just any class in your project
settings.embeddedDefaults[TestClass]
settings.usejavacp.value = true
val reporter = new StoreReporter()
val compiler = new Global(settings, reporter)    
val r = new Response[Unit]
val af = AbstractFile.getFile("/home/me/test.txt")
val filePath = af.path
val content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath).mkString
val sf = new BatchSourceFile(af, content)
val pos = new OffsetPosition(sf, content.length-1)
println("Content: ")
println (content)
println("Offset: "+content.length)

val allFiles = List(sf)
compiler.askReload(allFiles, r)

val response = new Response[List[compiler.Member]]
compiler.askTypeCompletion(pos, response)
//compiler.askScopeCompletion(pos, response)

val responseList = response.get(15000)

println("Size: "+responseList.size)
responseList.foreach(println _)
```

The "responseList" it's empty very time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard without seeing the actual test code. You probably need to have some logic that chooses between `askTypeCompletion` (basically, type members) vs `askScopeCompletion`. If there is no "dot" to your left, `askTypeCompletion` would probably not find anything.

You can have a look at how it's [tested](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/interactive/scala/tools/nsc/interactive/tests/core/CoreTestDefs.scala).